# Android Room how to auto generate a sequence count

Tags: android, android-room

My current Android application employs Room/SQLite database

One of my Room Entities requires a sequence column that increments each time I insert a new row.

I would like this sequence to be auto generated, however it seems autoGenerate is only available for PrimaryKey(s)

Is there any way I can have a Int column in Room auto increment when it is not a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, a column is autogenerated containing a unique value (which I believe is an integer). This is known as the `rowid`. This `rowid` column automatically increments every time you insert a row (more information about `rowid` [here](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)).

`rowid` isn't usually included in `SELECT *`, so you will need to manually include it in your DAO `@Query`. See below:

```java
@Query("SELECT *, rowid FROM my_table")
    fun get(): MyEntity
```

or in java:

```java
@Query("SELECT *, rowid FROM my_table")
    public MyEntity get();
```

Note that if your primary key is a integer, it will actually be an alias to the `rowid` column. Again, see the link I provided above for more info.

Hope this helps!